# Is this formula: $81n^2+135n+97$ wealth by prime numbers which $n$ is natural number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I made some effort to set a wealth quadratic formula for prime, I found this formula:

$A(n)= 81n^2+135n+97$, it gives primes for $n=0 $ to $n=18 $.

I would be like some one to show me if this really a wealth quadratic formula for primes for

large $n$?

Thank you for any replies or any comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "wealth quadratic formula"?

Comment: I mean with wealth by prime : large formula for prime

Comment: yes, this what i mean , i know that there r no general formula always gives primes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives primes for $26284$ of the integers from $1$ to $10^5$, so it's not too bad.  Not quite as good from that point of view as $n^2 + n + 41$, which produces  primes for $31984$ of those integers.

EDIT: your $A(n) = (9 n + 7)^2 + (9 n + 7) + 41$, so you just have a minor modification of the Euler polynomial.

Comment: thank you for your answer , do u mean is bad formula then Euler formula  ?

Comment: or do u see it interesting quadratic formula for primes ?

Comment: it is espicially modification and it's not avalaible with other formula then 9n+7 for n²+n+41 or 9n+8 for n²-n+41.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently known whether this polynomial represents an infinite number of primes.

The [Bouniakowski Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) implies that it does.

No polynomial $P(n)$ of degree $\ge 1$, with integer coefficients, can be prime for **all** large enough $n$.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer , pleas i know well this conjecture , just I mean if it is a best quadratic formula for primes , this what i mean .

Comment: Best in what sense?

Comment: in the sens of producing primes .

Comment: and mayeb give us a large prime number .

Comment: @user51189: As far as producing a long initial string, it is far from the famous quadratic of Euler. There are lists of initially "good" quadratics, but I do not have a url.

Comment: @ Robert Israel, i send to you a pdf about RH via ur email , pleas help me by your comments for my proof .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that it produces the most primes for a continuous range of n, no it is not.
The polynomial by Dress and Landreau (2002), Gupta (2006) produces primes for n = 0 to 56 (57 distinct primes)

$A(n) = |  \frac 1 4 (n^5-133n^4+6729n^3-158379n^2+1720294n-6823316) |$

Source [Prime-Generating Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html)

An alternate version generates the same numbers for n = 1 to 57

$A(n) = | \frac 1 4 (-8708852 + 2057776 n - 179374 n^2 + 7271 n^3 - 138 n^4 + n^5) |$